# prove that formula exists in first order logic expressing complete binary tree of depth $n$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Prove that for each finite binary tree $T$ there exists formula in
>   first order logic $\phi_n$ such that $T\models \phi_n$ iff $T$ is
>   complete binary tree with depth $n$.  Structure is two binary
>   relations: $L(x,y)$ iff $y$ is left son of father $y$, and analogically for $R(\cdot, \cdot)$. Additional difficulty is fact that formula can use only two variables, but it is possible to requantify them.

Being honestly I have no idea how to start. First of all, I don't know how to think about it - I have no root, moreover I have never solved similiar exercise.  I ask for help :)

Comment: "$y$ is left son of father $y$"? One of them should be $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$\psi_0(x)\equiv \forall y\,(\neg L(x,y)\land\neg R(x,y))$$
("$x$ is a leaf" or: "the subtree rooted at $x$ is complete binary of depth $0$") and then recursively
$$\psi_{n+1}(x)\equiv \exists y\,(L(x,y)\land\psi_n(y))\land  \exists y\,(R(x,y)\land\psi_n(y)).$$
Finally,
$$\phi_n\equiv \exists x\,(\psi_n(x)\land \forall y \,(\neg L(y,x)\land \neg R(y,x))) $$

Comment: thanks you very much! It was such easy!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139330/prove-that-sentence-in-first-order-logic-exists-directed-cycle-with-3n-dist  very similar :)

Comment: Generally I understand your solution. It means for examle, I can see that depth is $n$. And I can see that root has no parent. However, I cant see how you guarantee that internal node has exactly two sons ? You guarantee that there exists at least one left and at least one right son. But you solution seems to accept each tree of depth $n$.